# Determine the best host in multiplayer game on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa, game-center, multiplayer

I am using the following code to determine the best host to act as a server in a multiplayer iOS game with 2 users. The code is executed when all players has connected at the same time on all devices.

```
[myMatch chooseBestHostPlayerWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSString *playerID) {
    NSLog(@"The best host is: %@", playerID);
}];
```

The value of `playerID` is always null, which according to the documentation means that it couldn't determine the best host. I am testing the application on an iPhone with iOS 6.1 together with a simulator with version 6.1. The computer running the simulator and the iPhone are on the same wireless network. I've tested calling the code above in a continuous manner with an interval on both devices and found out that if one of the devices disconnect, it does determine a host.

Do I need two non-simulator devices to test this? Or what else could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it doesn't work with the simulator (or I haven't been able to make it work).

I do get a valid result most of the time when using 2 devices.
That said - it's not always consistent, so you definitely need a backup option for choosing the host.

Also

> If you intend to search for the best server using this method, all
>   devices in the match must be running on versions of Game Kit that
>   support this method, and every device in the match must call this
>   method at the same time.

This is out of the Multiplayer guide - do you call the method on both devices at the same time?